# IV for AES in ECB mode (algorithm 2.A in the PDF-2.0 spec)

Tags: pdf, aes, ecb

I am trying to implement "Algorithm 2.A" from the PDF-2.0 spec (pages 81-82 of ISO 32000-2:2020(E)).  The purpose of the algorithm is to retrieve the "file encryption key" of an encrypted PDF document, using a user-supplied password.  Step f of the algorithm starts with the following sentence:

> f) Decrypt the 16-byte Perms string using AES-256 in ECB mode with an
> initialization vector of zero and the file encryption key as the key. ...

My understanding is that ECB mode does not use an initialisation vector, so I am not sure what this means.  Is this a mistake in the spec?  How should I implement this step?

Many thanks,
Jochen

Comment: Having checked my code for this, It looks like you are right. The mistake is also in 7.6.4.4.12 (Algorithm 13). You can report it here: https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf-issues

Comment: Yeah, ECB mode doesn't use an IV. It shouldn't be used for message confidentiality either of course. I agree that *some* bad frameworks always require an IV (any CPA *secure* mode of operation require an IV or nonce, assuming the key may be reused) , however that doesn't mean that any specification should indicate one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @johnwhitington's comment (this is confusing and should be fixed in the spec), but also passing an "initialization vector of zero" (either as a single NULL value, or as a block of 16 zeros) is a common way to call cryptographic functions that support ECB in many frameworks. It is ignored by those functions, which is what you should do here.